# I renewed my passport and my visa is on my old passport. Will this create problems with Immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-renewals, democratic-republic-congo

My old passport has a 2-year validity visa for DR Congo expiring on 04.06.2016. It has only two blank pages remaining, so my boss told me to obtain a new passport, which I did. Presently I am on holiday and due to go back to DR Congo on 01.05.2016.

Will the Immigration officer accept my visa if it is in my old passport?

Comment: Did you renew your passport? Or did you ask for a second one (I would assume the former). Do you still have your old passport and is it still valid?

Comment: By "make new passport," do you mean that you got a new passport from the government, or you literally made (created) a new passport for yourself?

Comment: This happens all the time.  The general rule is that while a passport can expire, it does not invalidate existing visas inside the passport. Carry both and you'll be fine. If need be you can search 'transfer of conditions' or similar phrase to access the specific rule for the DRC.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121252/refused-entry-to-india

Answer (score 10):

You will need to carry both your old and new passport while traveling and immigration would have no problems with that. I have ten year and five year visas for many countries (including Canada and USA) and they are all on my old passport including an indefinite leave to remain in the UK stamp and I just carry both my passports with me.

Source : Own experience

Comment: It's important to note that there are exceptions to this rule (such as Australia). But it's generally true.

Comment: You guys are lucky you can keep your old passport. The last time I renewed my French passport, the French consulate kept my old passport as part of their new security protocol.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - you need to ask it back and they MUST give it back providing you have valid visas .

Comment: @MichaelHampton - As far as I know there is no exception for Australia . See my answer . ( also thee fact that I myself entered Australia with such a passport )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Australia visas are electronically tied to passport numbers, and [you're required to update your passport number](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/What-if-I-have-a-new-passport) when you receive a new passport. If you made such a journey, it's because the airline updated your details for you (which they're allowed to do).

Comment: @MichaelHampton know. That is my point . You can see reference [here](http://singapore.embassy.gov.au/sing/visas-faq.html) and [here](https://www.border.gov.au/aboutyourvisa#New%20passport) . at any rate - that does not make Australia an exception regarding valid visas in old passports . It just require an update to the details. This update can also be done on arrival ( true - takes some more time - but still can be done ) . Usually it is done by Airline on Check-in - which is what MOST Countries do anyhow without formally noticing it .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, I have dual citizenship, so I didn't face the same problem as the original poster since I didn't have an active visa in there. I only wanted my old French passport back for nostalgic reasons.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - I understand you completely . I am actually very upset about the fact that many countries ( soon - all ) stop the practice of stamps on the passport. Nostalgic too but  Also for practical reasons ( tracking own movements )

Answer (score 5):

You will have no problems .
Since I travel a LOT , I need to renew my passport every year almost . I have some long term visas ( Including 10 year visa ) . I just carry the ones I need together .

**Further Information regarding valid visa in expired passports :**

Some countries require that you will renew the visa if the passport is changed . Most don't . ( I never actually encountered it in case you have the old one )

That is the case for EXPIRED  passport - not for LOST or DAMAGED .There is a difference.

When you renew your passport , the consulate ( or respective minister ) is obliged by international law to give you back the old one providing it has valid visas from 3rd countries . legally speaking , the visas in your passport are properties of the country that issued them, and no other entity can invalidate or destroy them .

The most common way of invalidating a passport is to cut the "ears" or corners of external cover . That way no visa is damaged .

If you do not have valid visas some entities will punch a whole through the passport and give it back if specifically ASKED to.

In most cases ( depending on country of course ) , when applying for a new passport - the old passport will be validated with some kind of a note such as `" this passport is replacing an Expired document NO. XXX "` of one kind or another . This ties both old and new passport together .

Some countries require further documents on arrival, such as Australia and the Airline is actually the one to prepare it .

from the Australian Consulate immigration Info page

> If you have a valid visa associated with an expired passport (i.e.you
>   have been issued with a new passport since your current valid visa was
>   granted), you may travel carrying your old and new passports together
>   and the airline will arrange to have the details updated at time of
>   check-in. If so, you should check-in a little earlier to avoid delays.

So again - the direct answer - You will have no trouble as long as the visa page on old passport is valid and not physically damaged , and you have that with you  on arrival .